# Angular and Firestore: How merge data using observables?

Tags: angular, firebase, collections, google-cloud-firestore

> I´m trying to read a profile document with valueChanges and merge it with session data, but when I use forEach the returned observable is null (I´m new in both tecnologies).
>
> The code below returns a profile, as expected.

```
getProfileData() {
    return this.authService.user$.
        pipe(switchMap(user => { 
        return this.fstore.collection('profiles').
        doc(user.uid).valueChanges();}));}
```

> The code below returns NULL to observable.

```
  getProfileData() {
    return this.authService.user$.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        return this.fstore
          .collection('profiles').doc(user.uid)
          .valueChanges().forEach((p: Profile) => ({uid: user.uid, bio: p.bio}));
      })
    );
  }
```

> Componente ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.profile$ = this.uservice.getProfileData();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firestore's .valueChanges returns an observable so you could map your user data onto the firestore object using another pipe.

```
getProfileData() {
    return this.authService.user$.pipe(
      switchMap(user => this.mergeUserAndProfile(user)),
    );
  }

mergeUserAndProfile(user): Observable<any> {
  return this.fstore
  .collection('profiles')
  .doc(user.uid)
  .valueChanges()
  .pipe(
     map((p: profile) => {
       // Add user properties to profile
       p.uid = user.uid;
       return p
     })
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use one more pipe and with the "map" operator instead:

```js
getProfileData() {
    return this.authService.user$.pipe(
        switchMap(user => {
            return this.fstore
            .collection('profiles').doc(user.uid).valueChanges().pipe(
                map((p: Profile) => {
                    return {uid: user.uid, bio: p.bio}
                })
            );
        })
    );
}
```

Don't forget to import the map operator from the rxjs operators.

Comment: Thank you Braulio, so much !! It works!!! So simple! 
But what valueChanges().forEach() do?